# Find minimum deviation from vector from a matrix of possible vectors

Tags: r

I have the following data

```
set.seed(11)
Data<-rbind(c(1:5),c(2:6))


Candidates <- matrix(1:25 + rnorm(25), ncol=5,
dimnames=list(NULL, paste0("x", 1:5)))
 colnames(Data)<-colnames(Candidates)
```

I want to subtract each row of my Data from each row of the Candidate matrix
And return the minimal absolute difference
So for row one I want to find out the smallest amount of error possible

```
sum(abs(Data[1,]-Candidates[1,]))
sum(abs(Data[1,]-Candidates[2,]))
sum(abs(Data[1,]-Candidates[3,]))
sum(abs(Data[1,]-Candidates[4,]))
sum(abs(Data[1,]-Candidates[5,]))
```

In this case it's 38.15826. At the moment I'm not actually interested in finding out which Candidate row results in the smallest absolute deviation, I just want to know the smallest absolute deviation for each Data row.

I would then like to end up with a new dataset which has my original Data and the smallest deviation, e.g. row one would like this:

```
x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 MinDev 
1  2  3  4  5  38.15826
```

My real Candidate Matrix is relatively small but my real Data is quite large,
so at the moment I'm just building a loop that

```
Err[i,]<- min(rbinds( 
    sum(abs(Data[i,]-Candidates[1,])),
    sum(abs(Data[i,]-Candidates[2,]))...))
```

but I'm sure there's a better, more automated way to do this so that it can accomodate large Data matrices and Candidate matrices of different sizes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Make the example reproducible by using `set.seed` at the beginning.

Comment: Edited original question, I had forgotten to define seed. Apologies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sweep`, `rowSums`, and `apply` to automate this

```
sum(abs(Data[1,]-Candidates[1,]))  ## 38.15826
```

Testing on the first row of `Data`:

```
min(
    rowSums(abs(
                ## subtract row 1 of Data from each row of Candidates
                sweep(Candidates,2,Data[1,],"-"))))
## 38.15826
```

For convenience/readability, encapsulate this in a function:

```
getMinDev <- function(x) {
    min(rowSums(abs(sweep(Candidates,2,x,"-"))))
}
```

Now apply to each row of `Data`:

```
cbind(Data,MinDev=apply(Data,1,getMinDev))
```

There may be methods that are marginally faster than `sweep` (e.g. the matrix computations given in @e4e5f4's answer), but this should be a good baseline.  I like `sweep` because it is descriptive and doesn't depend on knowing that R uses column-major matrix ordering.

Comment: (+1) `sum(abs(vec1 - vec2))` is just the manhattan distance. `dist(rbind(vec1, vec2), method = "manhattan")`

Comment: @Arun, why not post as answer?  (Or edit my answer if you like.)

Comment: @BenBolker, added an answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `apply` with some matrix operations:

```
CalcMinDev <- function(x)
{
    m <- t(matrix(rep(x, nrow(Candidates)), nrow=nrow(Candidates)))
    min(rowSums(abs(m - Candidates)))
}

cbind(Data, MinDev=apply(Data, 1, CalcMinDev))
```

Comment: a bit shorter: `CalcMinDev <- function(x)min(colSums(abs(t(Candidates) - x)))`

Comment: +1, I tried to avoid creating a matrix, but I got lost in `t()` - `colSums` - `rowSums`

Answer (score 4):

Following @BenBolker's suggestion to turn my comment (using `dist` function with `method="manhattan"`) to an answer:

The idea: The trick is that if you supply a matrix to `dist`, it'll return the distance of all combinations back as a lower triangular matrix.

```
dist(rbind(Candidates, Data), method="manhattan")
#           1         2         3         4         5         6
# 2  8.786827                                                  
# 3 11.039044  3.718396                                        
# 4 16.120267  7.333440  6.041076                              
# 5 21.465682 12.678855 10.426638  5.345415                    
# 6 38.158256 45.763021 48.015238 53.096461 58.441876          
# 7 35.158256 40.763021 44.048344 48.096461 53.441876  5.000000
```

Here, 6th row and the 7th row (from index 1 to 5) are the distances you're interested in. So, basically, you'll just have to calculate indices to extract the elements you're interested.

---

The final code would look like:

```
idx1 <- seq_len(nrow(Data)) + nrow(Candidates)
idx2 <- seq_len(ncol(Candidates))
tt <- dist(rbind(Candidates, Data), method="manhattan")
transform(Data, minDev = apply(as.matrix(tt)[idx1, idx2], 1, min))
#   x1 x2 x3 x4 x5   minDev
# 6  1  2  3  4  5 38.15826
# 7  2  3  4  5  6 35.15826
```

Comment: Instead of computing a whole distance matrix, you can use `apply` to compute the distances just for the combinations you require, of course.

Comment: Really nice, this is great. I had actually the same thing before, and I solved it using `sweep`, but this is a lot better (I had used the eucl space and manhattan both).

Comment: One question though, would it be possible somehow to weigh certain deviations more, before it sums all the deviances?

Comment: @Dualinity, the `dist` function calls `C_Cdist` (C code). And there seems to be no options for this. Depending on the method, it *may* be possible to multiply the weights before calculating distance or so (not tested). But I agree such an option will be handy.